# How to use core-js polyfill in Nuxt3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, server-side-rendering, nuxt3

I want use core-js to polyfill old browser，I use it by import it in vue3 project main.ts file，but now I use nuxt3，I find there is no main.ts？Should I import it in app.vue？Or in plugins dir to define a plugin and then dynamic import using import function？How can I do？

I don't know how to do.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import core-js from any file, not just main.